# using for loop, all folders and files are listed. I want to display only a specified folder (sdcard) from the all listed folder

Tags: java, android

```
private String listfolders(String[] files, File f,String uri)
{     String msg = "";
      for ( int i=0; i<files.length; ++i )
      {
          File curFile = new File( f, files[i] );

                  boolean dir = curFile.isDirectory();  
                  // Show file size
                  String extra = "";
                  if ( curFile.isFile())
                  {
                          //extra = "target='_blank'"
                      extra = "";
                  }              
                  if ( dir )
                  {                  
                      Date lm =new Date(curFile.lastModified());    
                      String filedate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy'_'HH:mm:ss").format(lm);   
                           msg +="<b>";                                        
                           msg +="<tr>";                                  
                           msg +="<td>";
                           String path="/sdcard/temp/includes/fold.png";
                           //String p = "/Filemanager/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png";
                           msg +="<a "+extra + " href=\"" + encodeUri( uri + files[i] ) + "\">"  +"<img src=\""+ path +"\">"+  

                                   "<span class=\"fontf fcolor_black fsize\">"+ files[i] + "</span></a></td><td>";      
                           msg +="<td class=\"fcolor bfont\">";
                           msg +=filedate;
                           msg += "</font></td>";
                           msg +="<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"chkfolder\" value=" + files[i] + " /></td> ";
                           msg +="</tr>";
                           msg += "</b>";                           
                  }                   
          }

      return msg;
}
private String listfiles(String[] files, File f,String uri)
{ String msg = "";
      for ( int i=0; i<files.length; ++i )
      {
          File curFile = new File( f, files[i] );
                  boolean dir = curFile.isDirectory();  
                  // Show file size
                  String extra = "";
                  if ( curFile.isFile())
                  {
                          //extra = "target='_blank'";

                  }              
                  if ( !dir )
                  {                        
                          if ( curFile.isFile())
                          {                                  
                              Date lm =new Date(curFile.lastModified());    
                              String filedate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy'_'HH:mm:ss").format(lm);                                                             

                              msg +="<tr align=\"left\">";                                
                               msg +="<td align=\"left bfont\">";
                               String pa="/sdcard/temp/includes/file.jpg";
                               msg +="<a " + extra + " href=\"" + encodeUri( uri + files[i] ) + "\">"  +"<img src=\""+ pa +"\">"+
                                       "<span class=\"fontf fcolor_black fsize bfont\">"+
                                         files[i] + "<span></a></td><td>";      
                                  long len = curFile.length();
                                  msg += "<h4 class= \"fcolor_black\">";
                                  if ( len < 1024 )
                                          msg += curFile.length() + " bytes";
                                  else if ( len < 1024 * 1024 )
                                          msg += curFile.length()/1024 + "." + (curFile.length()%1024/10%100) + " KB";
                                  else
                                          msg += curFile.length()/(1024*1024) + "." + curFile.length()%(1024*1024)/10%100 + " MB";

                                  msg += "</h4></td>";
                                  msg +="<td class=\"fcolor bfont\">";
                                  msg +=filedate;
                                  msg += "</td>";
                          } 

                          msg +="<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"chkfile\" value=" + encodeUri(files[i]) + " /></td> ";
                          msg +="</tr>";                             
                  }                
          }

      return msg;
}
```

This is a small portion of our program to list the folders and files from the directory.
but I want to display only the specified folder and its files.`"/sdcard/folder name/"`. what should I do. i need some help. hope this website will help me

Comment: Have you even written this code yourself? Whats the exact problem you have? Just don't list the files and your done, can't be that hard.

Comment: using the for loop, it listed all the files and folders. i need to find a single folder(sdcard) from the all listed folder. and i want to display that specified folder(sdcard).

Comment: You did not show how you call your functions and what is the start directory. `listfolders(String[] files, File f,String uri)`. That is no good as nobody can see what 'files' has to do with 'f'. Better would be `listfolders(File f,String uri)`.

Comment: actually this program is done by my senior. he is resigned the job. and the responsibility become mine.will u help me to solve this problem. i tried to contact with my senior. but he is out of reach. if u send me ur email id. i will send u the program. will be more helpful for me.

Comment: It looks like your senior is Prakash? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600914

Answer (score 0):

just add condition

```
if ( dir && dir.getName().equals("foldername"))
                  {                  
                      Date lm =new Date(curFile.lastModified());    
                      String filedate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy'_'HH:mm:ss").format(lm);   
                           msg +="<b>";                                        
                           msg +="<tr>";                                  
                           msg +="<td>";
                           String path="/sdcard/temp/includes/fold.png";
                           //String p = "/Filemanager/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png";
                           msg +="<a "+extra + " href=\"" + encodeUri( uri + files[i] ) + "\">"  +"<img src=\""+ path +"\">"+  

                                   "<span class=\"fontf fcolor_black fsize\">"+ files[i] + "</span></a></td><td>";      
                           msg +="<td class=\"fcolor bfont\">";
                           msg +=filedate;
                           msg += "</font></td>";
                           msg +="<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"chkfolder\" value=" + files[i] + " /></td> ";
                           msg +="</tr>";
                           msg += "</b>";                           


         }
```

Comment: still.. it wont work. using this for loop, it listed all the files and folders. i need to find a single folder(sdcard) from the all listed folder. and i want to display that specified folder(sdcard)